# c++ program can you help me

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need code to The solution of this problems Use **Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0**

**Problem 1**:
Write a complete **C++** program that takes five floats `A, B, C, D, and E` and reorders them such that the smallest number is stored in `A`, and the largest number in `E`. Assume that the Five numbers are distinct (different). The program reads five floats from the keyboard then reorder them. The program should then print the values of `A, B, C, D, and E` after the Reorder.

**Problem 2**:
Write a **C++** program that reads in one of two characters input by the user. If the user input `C`, the program should calculate the area of a circle of radius input by the user.  If the user inputs `R`, the program calculates the area of the rectangle of width and length input by the user.

**Problem 3**:
Write a **C++** program that finds the roots of a second order equation (if they exist).

The equation will be:
`a(X^2)+bX+c`, the user will input the coefficients `a, b, c`. The program will first determine if the equation has roots or not. If it does, then the program will find these roots and display to the user:
`a(X^2)+bX+c=(X-R1)+(X-R2)` where `R1` and `R2` are the roots of the equation.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem? No one's going to do your (home)work for you.

Comment: We won't do your homework here.

Answer (score 0):

First program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    float A,B,C,D,E;
    float b,c,d,e;

    cout<<"This program takes 5 float inputs,reorder then print them";
    cout<<"\n Enter the first float";
    cin>>A;
    cout<<"\n Enter the first float";
    cin>>b;
    if (b>A){ 
        B=A;
        A=b;
    }
    else B=b;

    cout<<"\n Enter the second float";
    cin>>c;
    if (c>A){
        C=B;
        B=A;
        A=c;
    }
    else if (c>B){
        C=B;
        B=c;
    }
    else C=c;
    cout<<"\n Enter the third float";
    cin>>d;
    if (d>A){
        D=C;
        C=B;
        B=A;
        A=d;
    }
    else if (d>B){
        D=C;
        C=B;
        B=d;
    }
    else if(d>C){
        D=C;
        C=d;
    }
    cout<<"\n Enter the fourth float";
    cin>>e;
    if(e>A){
        E=D;
        D=C;
        C=B;
        B=A;
        A=e;
    }
    else if(e>B){
        E=D;
        D=C;
        C=B;
        B=e;
    }
    else if(e>C){
        E=D;
        D=C;
        C=e;
    }
    else if(e>D){
        E=D;
        D=e;
    }
    cout<<A<<"\t"<<B<<"\t"<<C<<"\t"<<D<<"\t"<<E;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: we are here to answer your questions, not solve ur homework. Start solving it and we'll help you with details, and correct your errors.